# Prove the inequality $|\mathrm e^{i\theta_1}-\mathrm e^{i\theta_2}|\le|\theta_1-\theta_2|$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, exponential-function

$$
|\mathrm e^{i\theta_1}-\mathrm e^{i\theta_2}|\le|\theta_1-\theta_2|
$$

This seems like a simple inequality but I cannot prove it simply. Do I have to consider Taylor expansions? Could anyone help me how to prove this inequality?

Comment: Are $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ real numbers?

Answer (score 7):

$e^{i\theta_1}$ and $e^{i\theta_2}$ lie on a circumference of radius equal to $1$ on the complex plane.

The LHS of your inequality can be interpreted as the length of the chord between $e^{i\theta_1}$ and $e^{i\theta_2}$, please check the red dotted line in the sketch below.

The RHS can also be seen as the length of the arc between the said points. Indeed the arc lenght in general is given by $ r (\alpha - \beta)$, where $\alpha - \beta$ is the angle subtended by the circular arc from the centre: in this case the radius $r$ is unitary.
[image]

The inequality has then a nice geometric interpretation: a circular arc is always longer than the chord between its starting and ending points.

Comment: Simply beautiful.

Comment: @Peter Szilas, no wonder Feynmann called Euler's identity "our jewel", it is simpy stunning

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&\theta&\mapsto&e^{i\theta}.\end{array}$$Then$$(\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}):\bigl|f'(\theta)\bigr|=1$$and therefore, by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), if $\theta_1,\theta_2\in\mathbb R$ and $\theta_1\neq\theta_2$, then$$\left|\frac{e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}}{\theta_1-\theta_2}\right|=\left|\frac{f(\theta_1)-f(\theta_2)}{\theta_1-\theta_2}\right|\leqslant1.$$

Comment: +1 for MVT applicable to vector valued functions. The result is not so popular as usual MVT and perhaps not everyone is aware why there is no analogue for MVT for such functions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: using Euler's formulas:
$$|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}|=|\cos{\theta_1}+i\sin{\theta_1}-\cos{\theta_2}-i\sin{\theta_2}|=$$
$$|-2\sin{\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}\sin{\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}+2i\cos{\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}\sin{\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}|=$$
$$2|\sin{\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}|\cdot |\sin{\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}-i\cos{\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}|\le $$
$$2|\sin{\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}|\cdot 1 \le 2\cdot \bigg|\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}\bigg|=|\theta_1-\theta_2|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\sin x|\le|x|, \sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos x}2$ and so
$$
|\mathrm e^{i\theta_1}-\mathrm e^{i\theta_2}|=|e^{i\theta_2}(e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}-1)|=|e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}-1|=\sqrt{(\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)-1)^2+\sin^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=\sqrt{2-2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=2|\sin\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}|\le |\theta_1-\theta_2|.
$$